# How to update amount of slides (Owl carousel)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, owl-carousel-2

I have owl-slider, the number of elements of which is filled depending on variable in session. This variable has default value, but it changes by executing some actions. How to re-generate my owl-slider after each change?

How it generates in view

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=Yii::$app->session['days_amount']; $i++): ?>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slide_top slide_day"><?= $i ?></div>
    <div class="slide_bot">
      <?= $planing_model->getCurMonthName(Yii::$app->session['curent_month']) ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

After updating DOM you can reinitialize owl carousel. i.e parent of all slides. Code might looks like as follows.

```
$('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

Class name may be depend as per your DOM.

Comment: there are ajax request that changes session variable. do i have to put this in success function? if so, it doesn't works

Comment: Yes you have to add this code in success after changing dom.

Comment: You need to refresh the **slider** (the parent of all the slides), not the slide and we don't know how you named your slider based on the provided markup. Something like this will do, `$('.owl-carousel or whatever class').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');`

Comment: @Ravenous Thank you for suggestion. :)

Comment: @markdeitchell you need to refresh parent of all slide i.e. parent of `.slide`